# From png to jpeg, what to do after huffman

Tags: jpeg

I've be trying to code in Python a script that takes as input a png image, and as output I'd like to create a .jpeg version of the same image.
This is for a school project, and the goal is to code every step of the process.
I've done most of the job right now (8x8 blocs, DCT, Quantization, Zigzag, Huffman...) but I find myself stuck at this place.

I've read many papers and tutorials, but I didn't find what am I supposed to do after the Huffman encoding.

Since I'm using the YUV color encoding, I have 2 matrices Cr and Cb and the code corresponding to the Huffman encoding of the Y matrix. What should I do with that ? My guess is I should create a file and write in it the Huffman Table, the Y matrix encoded and the two other matrices, but I can't just store data like that and expect the file to be read by a random image viewer outside the script.

I'm a little bit lost here, I hope I'm still clear... Anyway, some help would be greatly appreciated. Some explanations or even a simple link to a page I've missed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only book that actually explains the process for programmers without academic mumbo-jumbo

[https://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604434)